# Writing a Dictionary to Excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I have a dictionary with strings as the keys, and lists of strings as the values. I want to write the values to Excel so that the keys are on the top row and their values are in the corresponding columns. I already have some code below that will write the keys to the top row, but I'm not sure how to do the values. Thanks in advance!

```vb
Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
Excel._Workbook oWB = (Excel._Workbook) (oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
Excel._Worksheet oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet) oWB.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range oRng;

string[] saNames = dict.Keys.ToArray();

oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value).get_Resize(1, dict.Keys.Count);
oRng.Value = saNames;

oXL.Visible = true;
oXL.UserControl = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? Go over each key, writing it in the top row, then go over the strings in the values for successive keys.

```
int column = 1; // Initialize for keys.
foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{
    int row = 1; // Initialize for values in key.
    oSheet.Cells(row, column).Value = key;

    foreach (string value in dict[key])
    {
         row++;
         oSheet.Cells(row,column).Value = value;
    }

    column++; // increment for next key.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could just iterate over cells like that. I thought I had to use a range object.

Answer (score 3):

I know is not a EXCEL but if CSV format is good enough for you, then here is an example that worked for me.
of course using `System`, `System.IO` and `System.Linq`

```
    public static void DictToCsv(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            var csvLines = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                   dict.Select(d => d.Key + "," + d.Value));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath))
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, csvLines);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Enjoy